# Undo-tree style git in terminal

Tags: git, emacs

There's a package for Emacs which lets you use an undo-tree instead of just going forward and backwards with undo: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UndoTree

Is there a similar thing for git, which would let you look at a tree of commits and select one? Either on the command line or in Emacs?

[image]

Note: I'm new to Emacs, and I've installed the excellent Emacs Live - https://github.com/overtone/emacs-live - which seems to include magit. Emacs Live has a system to add customizations - the files go in ~/.live-packs/cannyboy-pack/ . Within that is an init.el file which references files within another folder - config. So I added (live-load-config-file "magit-custom.el") and added a magit-custom.el file in config with @event_jr's code, and then referenced that in ~/.live-packs/cannyboy-pack/init.el by adding (live-load-config-file "magit-custom.el")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Emacs, you can see a file's git commit log tree with magit's `magit-file-log`
command, and open up the log's diff by pressing <kbd>RETURN</kbd>.  We can
build on top of magit and Emacs's internal version control aware features to
visit the file directly.

1. Download install [magit](https://github.com/magit/magit).
2. Add to your "init.el"

   ```
   (defun my-magit-visit-file-at-commit (&optional other-window)
     "Visit current commit's file in another window.

   This command makes sense from a `magit-file-log' buffer. "
     (interactive "P")
     (magit-section-action (item info "visit")
       ((commit)
        (let ((filename (expand-file-name (car magit-refresh-args)
                                          (concat (magit-git-dir) "../"))))
          (if (file-readable-p filename)
              (progn
                (find-file-noselect filename)
                (with-current-buffer (find-buffer-visiting filename)
                  (vc-revision-other-window info)))
            (message "not able to access %s" filename))))))

   (eval-after-load "magit.el"
     '(define-key magit-log-mode-map (kbd "C-c o") 'my-magit-visit-file-at-commit))
   ```
3. restart Emacs
4. open the file whose commit history you're interested in.
5. `M-x magit-file-log`
6. go to interesting commit press <kbd>C-c o</kbd>

**edit** fix missing keymap specification.

Comment: Thanks, I've added some detail to my question. I couldn't get your code to work (not enough arguments in the define-key statement). So I changed it to _'(define-key **global-map** (kbd "C-c o")_ etc…. However I get this error in the minibuffer: not able to access /path/to/code/MyCode/HEAD

Comment: Sorry, got it working. I was going into magit-log instead of magit-file-log. Thanks for the code. Still not sure if I should be using global-map.

Comment: It puts files with the commit number after the filename, like so filename.~512b384~ ... could it replace the file completely, or is this against git's philosophy?

Comment: I fixed the code to specify the right keymap.  It is possible to replace the working tree's file's contents, but that would get confusing pretty quickly.

Comment: I'm getting `Symbol's function definition is void: magit-section-action` with the newest version of magit I got from elpa (20151006.1359), and I had to use the `global-map` because `magit-log-mode-map` is no longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

I think that [magit](https://github.com/magit/magit) is what you are looking for.
[Here is a good tutorial](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-vcs/EmacsGit.html) showing it's use.

You should also have a look at [Egg](https://github.com/bogolisk/egg), which is said to have a better user interface.